# Shouldn't we use microformats if we are making accessible site?

Tags: xhtml, accessibility, web-standards, screen-readers, microformats

Is microformat's classes structure good for Screen reader?

```
<div class="vcard">
  <span class="fn">Gregory Peck</span>
  <a class="org url" href="http://www.commerce.net/">CommerceNet</a>
  <div class="adr">
    <span class="type">Work</span>:
    <div class="street-address">169 University Avenue</div>
    <span class="locality">Palo Alto</span>,  
    <abbr class="region" title="California">CA</abbr>  
    <span class="postal-code">94301</span>
    <div class="country-name">USA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tel">
   <span class="type">Work</span> +1-650-289-4040
  </div>
  <div class="tel">
    <span class="type">Fax</span> +1-650-289-4041
  </div>
  <div>Email:
   <span class="email">info@commerce.net</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this (assume both code with same content info)

```
<p><strong>London</strong>
<br/>
607,5th Floor, Oxford Towers,
<br/>
Airport Road, Kodihalli
<br/>
London 560 008
<br/>
Phone: 91-80- 4115 1705-706
<br/>
Fax: 91-80- 41151707
<br/>
Email:<a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com"></a>
<br/>
Website:<a href="http://abc.com">abc.com</a>
</p>
```

Which method is good for accessibility and text only browser? How screen reader will behave with both method?

Comment: I'd recommend reading Transcending CSS. It's all about semantically correct HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 3):

[Microformats](http://microformats.org) are not about presentational, [they are about](http://microformats.org/about) **semantics**.

`<span>foo</span>` renders the same as `<span class="bar">foo</span>`, and this is all microformats are about : adding standardized class names to HTML elements for a given and identified "thing" (like a person, eg: hcard), nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think any screen readers make any use of microformats yet, but microformats don’t hurt screen reader users ([except for the datetime design pattern](http://microformats.org/wiki/datetime-design-pattern#accessibility_issues)) either.

Please note that microformats generally only specify class names, so you don’t have to just use `<div>`s and `<span>`s with microformats — paragraphs and lists and whatnot are just fine, where appropriate.